# Is it normal for ground to settle like this, and how can fix it?

Tags: concrete, landscaping, sewer

Before we bought this house, they repaired/replaced the sewer line out front. Refilling the dirt and replacing part of the sidewalk. They didn't really leave a mound of dirt, but I also don't know how much was dug.

3-4 months later, I noticed the ground has sunk below the walk way, a lot. There's 4-6in of space through most of it, some more. Is it just dirt settling and how can I fill this?
Almost all of the new part is no longer touching dirt,  and some of the old part is unsupported as well.
[image: b]

Comment: `Is it just dirt settling?` that depends entirely on what is underneath

Answer (score 2):

The only fill that will not settle is sand. Try to push as much sand as you can under the slab. On the sides, you can just backfill with loam and some grass seed.

The other alternative would be to use a wet saw to cut the walkway into sections, lift each one, use a compactor on the soil, then add 4" of gravel, then 4" of sand, and reposition the slabs. If it sounds like a lot of work, it's because it is. If it were my house, I'd just add soil and grass seed.